# Text to Speech in Windows Store App using Speech Synthesizer

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, windows-8.1

I am running this sample of Hello world
My code is

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
            Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

            var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream,stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
```

when I debug it, I get an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in SunnahForKids.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Comment: Are you sure all DLLs that has been referenced are available?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx)

**Requirements**

Minimum supported client:  Windows 8.1

Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2012 R2

Minimum supported phone: Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

Namespace: Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis, Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis [C++]

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because the voice is not installed on the device. To solve it just add a try catch block and it will only "speak" when the voice related to the region and language of your app IS installed. Otherwise it will run without speaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dependency walker to view the dependency of system.speech.dll, it would tell you that 
"Error: Modules with different CPU types were found."
Set CPU to be x64 in Visual Studio might solve your problem. It works for me.